# How do I assign an index to list of buttons in the listview?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

```
Widget inEngTaskBody(BuildContext context) {

return ListView(
scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
children: <Widget>[

  Center(
    child: Text(
      'General Condition',
      style: TextStyle(
        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
        fontSize: 25,
      ),
    ), //Text
  ), // Center

  OutlinedButton(
    child: Text(inEngTaskList().genCond[0]),
    onPressed: () {},
  ), //GCbutton1
  SizedBox(height: 10),

  OutlinedButton(
    child: Text(inEngTaskList().genCond[1]),
    onPressed: () {},
  ), //GCbutton2
  SizedBox(height: 10),

  OutlinedButton(
    child: Text(inEngTaskList().genCond[2]),
    onPressed: () {},
  ), //GCbutton3
  SizedBox(height: 10),
```

How do I assign each button an index? Was thinking of using the `scrolltoindex()` function. I have seen many examples using `listview.builder`, however, I am making a customized list view. I do not intend to use builder as each button will have a specific task upon `onpressed()`. Many of the examples are of non-button listview.

Appreciate the help thank you.

This code is to be assigned to the

```
body: inEngTask(context)
```

in my `main.dart`.

Using Bernard Hur's suggestion:
[image: Using Bernard Hur's suggestion]

What I am trying to achieve.
[image]

****EDIT****
The texts in each button is stored in a list. If I could index each button, I can create a search bar to compare with the list and scroll to the index of the button. However, I do require some texts as header to some of the buttons, hence the looping listview.builder is a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ListView.builder` instead of `ListView(children:...)` version as follow:

```
ListView.builder(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  itemCount: NumberOfButtons, // for example 3
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Column(
      children:[
         Text("your header"),
         // you can add other widgets as well
         OutlinedButton(
            child: Text(inEngTaskList().genCond[index]),
            onPressed: ()=>mainFunction(index),
         ), 
      ]
    );
  }
);
```

see [this][1] for more examples. Also, about the main function you have two options:

1. having a list of functions like `functionList` and use them based on an index of the item in list view as `onClick:functionList[index]`.
2. or use a `mainFunction` that decides the operation based on given `index` like the above example. You can handle different events based on this function:

```
void mainFunction(int index){
   if(index==0){//do sth}
   else if(index==1){//do sth else}
   // and so on...
}


  [1]: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html
```

Comment: Hello, but this would not allow me to give custom onPressed instructions to each button as this acts like a loop, generating the buttons. Kindly advice if I am wrong. 

Also, how would I include text headers? Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Oh, actually I just gave an example. You can add more features based on your need. I have updated my answer, so you can find out how to deal with different methods for each button and also how you can various widgets to each element of `ListView` using `Column` (or `Row`). let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: Hi Abbasihsn, thanks for the response! I get the idea of the function for the onpressed. however, the method you suggested is similar to that of Bernard's. I got the result as seen above. I have attached the outlook of what I am trying to achieve. Would appreciate the assistance. My apologies for the lack of information.

Comment: @JohnnyAppleseed happy to help. It is ok, but I think you can upvote whoever helped you to find a solution and tag one answer as an acceptable one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you wanted auto-scroll listview or a just listview built by index. The below is the listview made by index.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: inEngTaskList().length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  final String text = inEngTaskList().genCond[index] as String;

  return Column(
    children: [
      const Center(
      child: Text(
        'General Condition',
        style: TextStyle(
        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
        fontSize: 25,
        ),
       ), //Text
      ), // Center

      OutlinedButton(
        child: Text(text),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 10),

      ],
    );
   },
  );
```

Comment: Hello, I tried out your method. It yielded me the above picture. Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Happy to hear that ^ㅁ^

Comment: Hi Bernard, I am so sorry. I think I made a mistake by not being clear enough. I have uploaded a photo of what I am trying to achieve. I am not sure if ListView.builder might be appropriate in this case. Is there a work around for this? 

I did the above without listview, but I could not index each button. Appreciate your assistance. Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late response. Problem solved? If not, pls send a mail to me. (hurgoon@gmail.com) I can't get about new problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

try this using index based Condition ..!!

```
 ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 8,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (index == 0) {
                return Container(
                  child: Text('Text$index'),
                );
              }
              if (index == 1) {
                return Container(
                  child: Text('Text$index'),
                );
              }
              if (index == 2) {
                return Container(
                  child: Text('Text$index'),
                );
              }
              if (index == 3) {
                return Container(
                  child: Text('Text$index'),
                );
              }
              if (index == 4) {
                return Container(
                  child: Text('Text$index'),
                );
              }
              if (index == 5) {
                return Container(
                  child: Text('Text$index'),
                );
              }
              if (index == 6) {
                return Container(
                  child: Text('Text$index'),
                );
              }
              if (index == 7) {
                return Container(
                  child: Text('Text$index'),
                );
              } else {
                return Container(
                  child: Text('Text'),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).